# Optimizing a where clause (short circuiting), SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

How can one optimize this query:

```
declare @MyParam nvarchar(100) = 25846987;

select top 100 * from MySelectTable
where
(MyParam = @MyParam)
OR
(@MyParam = 0 and MyParam in (SELECT MyParam FROM aMassiveSlowTable WHERE Id = 'random1'))
OR
(@MyParam = 1 and MyParam in (SELECT MyParam FROM aMassiveSlowTable WHERE Id = 'random2'))
OR
(@MyParam = 2 and MyParam in (SELECT MyParam FROM aMassiveSlowTable WHERE Id = 'random3'))
```

When i use only this part:

```
declare @MyParam nvarchar(100) = 25846987;

select top 100 * from MySelectTable
where
(MyParam = @MyParam)
```

It returns in 1 second.

When using all the parameters, it takes about 5 minutes.

I believe it's because it's scanning aMassiveSlowTable when all it has to do is match MyParam = @MyParam.

How do I make it skip all the other comparisons if @MyParam matches MyParam? I tried using CASE statements but they don't work with **IN** clauses. I tried rearranging the AND's in the paranthesis and even adding additional filtering to *aMassiveSlowTable*.

If @MyParam does not match MyParam, it's ok if the query takes a little longer.

Comment: There's *no* guarantee on the order in which SQL Server will evaluate parts of a single query (e.g. it might evaluate a calculation for the `SELECT` clause for a row that would, properly, be excluded by the `WHERE` clause).

Comment: @Damien I'm starting to think so.

Comment: Can you post the definitions of the two tables, the indices and the execution plan?

Comment: Not now really (later, it's a little complicated). Isn't the performance boost after removing everything after the first `OR` indicative enough?

Comment: Do you have indexes in the two `MyParam` columns? Are these 2 columns of the exact same datatype?

Comment: Indexing or re-indexing is out of the question (for now). Yes they are. It should be of no importance for the question (not the query).

Comment: What if you add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`?

Comment: @Martin Smith, make this an answer because this does it (`OPTION (RECOMPILE)`). Also, what with the downvote?

Comment: I've tried testing it from multiple sessions, so i don't know how does it actually work?

Comment: @AdamRobinson That **is** impossible to guarantee in SQL Server without a `CASE` expression. See [SQL Server should not raise illogical errors](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/537419/sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors)

Comment: @MartinSmith: So it is; I guess I've been lucky so far! I've removed my previous comment and I'll be sure to use the `CASE` expression in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This might fix it
In the where it should get evaluated early

```
(MyParam in (SELECT MyParam FROM aMassiveSlowTable WHERE Id = 'random1' and @MyParam = 0 ))
```

or

```
declare @MyParam nvarchar(100) = 25846987;
select * 
from MySelectTable
where MyParam = @MyParam 
union
select *  
from MySelectTable
join aMassiveSlowTable as Slow 
 and Slow.MyParam = MySelectTable.MyParam 
 and Slow.ID = 'random0'
where @MyParam = 0
union
select *  
from MySelectTable
join aMassiveSlowTable as Slow 
 and Slow.MyParam = MySelectTable.MyParam 
 and Slow.ID = 'random1'
where @MyParam = 1
union
select *  
from MySelectTable
join aMassiveSlowTable as Slow 
 and Slow.MyParam = MySelectTable.MyParam 
 and Slow.ID = 'random2'
where @MyParam = 2
```

or and play with the join hint

```
declare @MyParam nvarchar(100) = 25846987;
select top 100 * 
from MySelectTable
left join aMassiveSlowTable as Slow 
  on Slow.MyParam in (1,2,3)  -- now the optimizer has something hard to evalate
 and Slow.MyParam = MySelectTable.MyParam 
 or (Slow.MyParam = 0 and Slow.ID = 'random0')
 or (Slow.MyParam = 1 and Slow.ID = 'random1')
 or (Slow.MyParam = 2 and Slow.ID = 'random2')
where MyParam = @MyParam
```

Comment: I tried the first part and it does not help (that's what i meant when i said _adding additional filtering to aMassiveSlowTable_. I will try the other approaches.

Answer (score 0):

As to the performance aspect of your question "when using all the parameters" you may want to review the following kb:

FIX: Poor performance when you run a query that contains correlated AND predicates in SQL Server 2008 or in SQL Server 2008 R2 or in SQL Server 2012

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2658214